# Pull data into a list for custom content type?

Tags: nodes

Hopefully this is a quick question!  I'm working on a custom content type for users to create something similar to blog posts.  We'll have different authors who will be credited, so I need a drop down list so when a user writes the post, they can select the author.

The trouble is, I need to list to be auto populated from the data that is stored in a different field.  We have a content type called (you guessed it) authors.  It allows us to fill out name, field of expertise, etc.

So, how can I add an AUTHOR NAME list to my BLOG custom content type?

Thanks!
-JB

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to create your 'author name' field, which will reference your `authors` content type.